# Error CORS al realizar llamada con post en Angular 8

Tags: php, angular, rest

estoy empezando con Angular, estoy probando llamadas usando get sobre un backend php y no estoy teniendo ningún problema, pero al probar un login usando post me da el siguiente error:

El código es el siguiente tanto la parte de Angular como el controller del backend:

**login.component.html**

```
    <div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
    <div id="formContent">
      <!-- Tabs Titles -->

      <!-- Icon -->
      <div class="fadeIn first">
        <img src="#" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />
      </div>

      <!-- Login Form -->
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="alias" [(ngModel)]="alias" class="fadeIn second" name="alias" placeholder="alias">
        <input type="text" id="password" [(ngModel)]="password" class="fadeIn third" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In" name="login" (click)="doLogin(alias, password, $event)">
      </form>

      <!-- Remind Passowrd -->
      <div id="formFooter">
        <a class="underlineHover" href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Manager/app/src/app/app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  constructor(private appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  doLogin(alias : String, password : String, event : Event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var login = this.appService.postLogin(alias, password).subscribe(data =>{this.data = data});
    console.log('data: '+this.data);
  }
}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class AppService {
      login = 'localhost/server/?login';
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      postLogin(alias : String, password : String){
        return this.http.post(this.login,
        {
            "alias": alias,
            "password": password,
        });
      }
    }
```

Controller PHP

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization');
    header('Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8');
    include_once('model/user.php');


    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        $data = User::login($_POST['alias'], $_POST['password']);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

En teoría php debería devolverme un OK o un KO en caso de encontrar o no coincidencias, he probado metiendo todos los encabezados que se me han ocurrido pero no consigo que haga la petición correctamente.

Añado captura desde el Network:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

file_get_contents('php://input'), true) me lo devuelve nulo en las llamadas. Por otro lado no consigo que entre en el $_POST['login']

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede hacer de varias maneras.
Primero envía los headers, si quieres envía los datos tipo json.

```
postLogin(datos){
    let headers=new HttpHeaders();
    let body=JSON.stringify({"datos":datos});

    headers.append('Content-Type' , 'application/json');
    return this.http.post(this.myurl+"login.php",body,{headers:headers}).pipe(map(res=>{

       return res;
     }));
   }
```

Dese angular y ahora en php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Desde php, revisa si la variable contiene info.
Otra manera que podrías hacer es enviar los datos por la url, login?user=.....&password=....

o en Angular con httpParams, con este puedes declarar las variables tipo url.

Espero que te sirva Un saludo.

Comment: Perfecto, ya no tengo el error, muchas gracias. Lo que ahora no recibo es la respuesta de php :(

Comment: $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); echo json_encode($data); // si lo has realizado con json revisar la pestaña de network

Comment: Pero con isset($_POST['login']) en PHP no puedo detectar ya esta request como hago con los get ¿no? Osea si paso la petición a un get sí recivo respuesta pero con post no estoy recibiendo

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes adjuntar una captura de la url, conforme la llama, en la pestaña de network, así puede quedar un poco mas.
El servicio sería algo así
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppService {
  login = 'localhost/server/login.php';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postLogin(alias : String, password : String){
    return this.http.get(this.login+'?id='+alias+'&password='+password);
  }
}
```

He modificado un par de cosas, para que en principio funcione.
y en php podrías ver el
si

```
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_POST);
```

Que repuesta muestra

Comment: usando GET sí que me funciona correctamente, quiero que me funcione por POST, he ampliado info en mi pregunta, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Te respondo mañana que me pillas un poco liado

Comment: he avanzado un poco más, estaba pansando mal los datos porque estaba probando las llamadas con Postman, pasandole bien el JSON ya me devuelve datos el file_get_contents('php://input'), me falta solo saber cómo puedo saber a qué hace referencia (osea cómo puedo leer desde php ese ?login para saber que la acción se refiere al login del usuario. Responde cuando puedas, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que lo hagas mediante json,  a la larga es mucho mas cómodo,

```
enviarLogin(alias, password) {
    let datos ={ alias: alias, password:password };                
        let headers=new HttpHeaders();                                 
        headers.append('Content-Type' , 'application/json');
        return this.http.post(this.myurl+"login.php",body,{headers:headers}).pipe(map(res=>{
          console.log(res)
           return res;
         })); }
```

en php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo json_encode($data);
die();
```

Así puedes ver la respuesta del php y conforme le llega, tendría que ser algo así,
$data['alias'];// para coger alias.
Pero revisa la respuesta y te aseguras, tanto en consola, como en la pestaña de network.
Se que puede parecer difícil, pero una vez te cojas seguro que te ayuda.
Espero que te sirva.
Un saludo